# Arduino SoftwareSerial wrong values

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, serial-communication, bitset, software-serial

The wrong 1 byte values are being sent or received(I don't know) when using SoftwareSerial between Arduino leonardo and Arduino UNO.
UNO and Leo are connected via:

- gnd
- pin 9 and 8

here is the code that runs on leonardo:

```
//LEO
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 9;
const byte txPin = 8;

SoftwareSerial sserial (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  sserial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(sserial.available())
  {
    uint8_t recv = 0;
    sserial.readBytes(&recv, 1);
    Serial.println(recv);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      if(bitRead(recv, i))
      {
        Serial.print("1 ");
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("0 ");
      }
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

and here is the code that runs on UNO:

```
//UNO
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 8;
const byte txPin = 9;

uint8_t count = 0;
unsigned long last_send = millis();

SoftwareSerial sserial (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  sserial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(millis() - last_send > 500)
  {
    count++;
    last_send = millis();
  }
  sserial.write(&count, 1);
  delay(100);
}
```

and here is the output I'm getting in the Serial Monitor of Arduino Leonardo:

```
0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
4
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
4
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
4
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
4
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
4
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
5
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
6
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
7
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
8
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
8
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
8
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
8
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
8
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
9
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
13
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
14
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
15
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
16
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
17
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
17
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
17
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
17
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
17
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
18
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
19
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
21
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
20
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
21
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
21
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
21
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
22
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
23
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
24
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
25
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
26
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
26
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
26
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
26
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
26
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
27
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
28
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
29
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
30
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
30
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
30
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
30
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
30
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
252
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
31
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
31
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
31
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
31
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
31
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
32
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
33
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
34
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
35
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
35
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
35
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
35
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
35
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
36
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
37
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
38
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
39
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
39
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
39
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
39
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
39
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
40
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
41
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
42
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
43
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
44
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
44
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
44
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
44
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
44
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
45
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
46
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
47
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
48
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
49
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
49
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
49
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
49
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
49
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
50
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
51
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
52
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
53
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
54
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
54
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
54
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
54
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
54
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
55
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
56
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
57
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
57
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
57
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
57
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
57
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
58
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
59
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
60
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
61
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
62
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
62
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
62
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
62
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
62
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
63
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
192
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
193
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
194
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
195
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
195
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
195
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
195
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
195
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
196
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
197
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
198
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
199
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
71
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
199
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
199
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
199
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
71
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
200
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
200
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
200
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
72
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
200
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
201
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
202
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
75
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
203
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
75
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
75
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
75
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
204
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
205
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
77
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
77
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
205
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
77
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
77
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
206
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 
78
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
78
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
206
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 
206
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 
78
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
79
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
208
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
208
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
208
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
208
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
208
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
209
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
210
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
83
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
83
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
83
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
211
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
211
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
211
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
212
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
213
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
85
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
85
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
85
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
213
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
214
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
86
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
86
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
214
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
214
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
214
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
87
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
216
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
89
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
217
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
89
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
217
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
217
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
89
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
218
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
90
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
90
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
90
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
218
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
91
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
92
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
220
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 
92
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
220
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 
92
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
92
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
93
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
93
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
93
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
93
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
93
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
94
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
95
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
224
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
225
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
226
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
226
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
226
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
226
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
226
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
99
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
99
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
227
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
227
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
99
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
227
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
228
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
228
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
228
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
228
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
228
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
100
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 
229
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
229
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
101
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 
101
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 
229
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
229
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
102
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
230
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
102
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
230
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
102
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
103
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
232
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
232
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
232
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
232
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
104
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
232
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
105
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
105
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
233
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
233
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
233
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
105
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
234
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 
234
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 
106
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
234
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 
106
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
107
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
108
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
236
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 
236
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 
108
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
108
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
236
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
109
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
110
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
111
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
111
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
111
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
111
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
111
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
240
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
241
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
113
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
113
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
113
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
113
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
241
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
114
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
114
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
242
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
114
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
114
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
242
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
115
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
116
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
244
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
244
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
116
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
116
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
117
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
118
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
119
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
120
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
248
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
248
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
248
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
120
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
121
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
122
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
123
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
124
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 
125
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 
126
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
127
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

You can see that the values received are not in order they should be in. Format: value \n its bit representation.
Any ideas  what I might be doing wrong or why this is not working properly.

I have tried all the combinations of pins 8 - 13.
I was expecting the values to be in order as they should be, each next incremented by one(on half a second basis).

Comment: use lower baud rate. on Leonardo you can use hardware Serial1

Comment: You mean rx and tx pins at the bottom? Otherwise if u mean scl and sda pins... I know, however I am using USB host shield attacked to my leonardo therefore that is not an option

Comment: USB Host Shield uses SPI. Serial1 on Leonardo are pins 0 and 1 labeled RX1 and TX1

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be the baud rate
I was able to get reliable data transmission with baudrates up to including 74880